# Definition of sequential compactness

Tags: general-topology, compactness

The definition I have for sequential compactness goes like this:

A subspace $ K \subseteq X $, $X$ a metric space, is sequentially compact if all sequences $(x_n)$, $x_n \in K$ have a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_i})$, $x_{n_i} \rightarrow x \in K$.

My interpretation of this is the following statement:

Let  $ K \subseteq X $, $X$ a metric space. Then:

all sequences $(x_n)$, $x_n \in K$ have a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_i})$, $x_{n_i} \rightarrow x \in K$ $\implies$ $K$ is compact.

But I was wondering if/when this is true in the other direction? I thought that if $K$ is compact and it contains *some* sequence, then *that* sequence must have a convergent subsequence? But perhaps there is no guarantee that $K$ contains a sequence? But then if $K$ is non-empty, it must have points in it which form some sort of sequence?

I'd be grateful if someone could clarify this for me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitions in math are *biconditional statements*. Confusingly, they are often not stated that way. However, it is the case that

$$\text{All sequences $(x_n)$ with elements in $K$ have a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_i})$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $K$ is compact}$$

The case of the empty set is interesting. As an analogy, suppose I said "all the irrational integers are zero". That statement is nonsense, clearly, but it's also **true**. Since there are no irrational integers, it doesn't matter what statement I make about them. Such a statement is said to be "vacuously true".

So if $K$ is empty, it *is* true that every sequence in $K$ contains a convergent subsequence, but it's vacuously true since $K$ does not contain any sequences.

Comment: Some professors always use "iff" in definitions, but I always find it to be pedantic XD

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $X$ is a metric space and that $k \subset X$. A set $K$ of a topological space is said to be compact, when for every collection of open sets $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ such that $K \subset \cup_{i \in I} U_i$ there exists a finite number of indexes, said $i_1, \cdots, i_r$ such that $K \subset U_{i_1} \cup \cdots \cup U_{i_r}$. This is called the Borel-Lebesgue property. Now, it can be shown that, inside metric spaces, this property is **equivalent** to the property of sequential compactness. Therefore $K$ is compact (almost by definition) **if and only if** $K$ is sequentially compact.

Answer (score 1):

In general compactness and sequential compactness are *not* equivalent, neither one necessarily implies the other. This equivalence is true, however, for metric spaces.

So a metric space is compact if and only if it is sequentially compact.

For this reason, it is useful and helpful *not* to think about the definition of "sequential compactness implies compactness".

So your interpretation of the *definition* is wrong. The definition merely states that a set is sequentially compact if whenever you have a sequence in $K$, it has a convergent subsequence whose limit is also in $K$.

What you have interpreted, however, is that a sequentially compact metric space is in fact compact. And as mentioned before, the other direction is also true: a compact metric space is in fact sequentially compact.

To see why, note that if $(x_n)$ is a sequence of elements from $K$, a compact subset of $X$, and assume towards contradiction that $(x_n)$ does not have a convergent subsequence; then for every $x\in K$ let $U_x$ be an open set containing only finitely many of the $x_n$'s (such $U_x$ can be found, since otherwise $x$ is a limit of a subsequence). Now $\{U_x\mid x\in K\}$ is an open cover of $K$, refining it to a finite subcover gives us at least one of the open sets with infinitely many of the $x_n$'s, which is a contradiction to how we chose the $U_x$'s.